# The correct way of layout declaration?

Tags: layout, certification

I'm doing some Magento 2 certification test questions. There's one question I do not understand.

The question is as the screenshot. My answer is **D**, but the correct answer from the test is ***B***

[image]

I've been working a lot with layout xml, and I'm quite convinced ***D*** is the correct way to declare a custom layout. But if B is the correct answer, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node attributes are ordered alphabetically

This is the clean way to write XML

Comment: so B (second answer Marked with Green color from screenshot) is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes b : Class Name Template

Comment: Plus doesn't mention anything about referencing your own template logic in your theme

Comment: But it's a awful question as D could be correct if you are writing something for your own extension. A and C or not correct because of syntax.